# What is the difference between multi-layer, multiplex and heterogeneous networks?

Tags: social-networks, network-analysis

I know when we have multiple networks connected to each other, we can call every network a layer and the whole network is called multi-layer. But I don't know what is the difference between multi-layer and multiplex and heterogeneous?

Thanks

Comment: What have you heard the phrase "multiplex and heterogeneous" in this context?  Can you give context, citation, a quotation showing how it is used, etc.?  I've never heard that phrased used in this context.

Comment: @D.W. The Op should be specific,all those networks can be found in various fields ie neuroscience,physics and data communications,so I'm also not really figure it out perfectly.

Comment: @quintumnia Sorry, I meant social networks.